# How to change PHD sponsored by Marie Skłodowska-Curie Fellowship

Tags: phd, changing-fields, marie-curie

I come from an EU country, and I am doing a PHD funded by a Marie Skłodowska-Curie Innovative Training Network (ITN).

The problem is that, after almost a year spent here, I realize that I do not like my subject, nor the professors. I would like to continue my PhD studies, but I need to make a change (professor, subject, maybe country).

**I don't know if it is possible to make such a change, while maintaining the Marie Skłodowska-Curie fellowship.**

It is hard to find an answer because I prefer not to talk about this with my professors. Also, I asked a Marie Skłodowska-Curie project secretary, and she only told me that I can quit the PhD any time without any financial consequences for me.

I prefer not to give details about subject, the university, or the names of my professors. Still, feel free to ask me if you need more details and I hope I could make my question clearer thanks to your feedback!

Thank you all!

Comment: I don't know how it really works, but as far as I understand, the process for Marie Curie Fellowship is the same. Could you, please, offer the link for ERC? I would like to give it a try.

Comment: By ERC you mean the following one?  https://www.erc.edu/

Comment: No, this is the ERC: https://erc.europa.eu/ Just a comment: consider what you're trying to do. Your supervisor(s) obtained some kind of funding and awarded the PhD fellowship to you. Now you want to take this fellowship, leave your lab and supervisor(s), and continue a PhD elsewhere. Regardless of any issue with your supervisor(s), it's rather clear that it's not going to happen...

Comment: When the secretary told you there would not be financial consequences for you they probably mean that you **won't have to pay back the fellowship** if you quit before completing your PhD.

Comment: I am a current MSCA ESR myself. I can tell you this for sure: if you quit working with your professor, you will lose your fellowship/salary. Think of it as quitting your job. You will not owe anything to anyone, but you will for sure not be able to take the fellowship with you somewhere else.

If you have an unproductive relationship with your professor but the fellowship is important for you, you could consider getting advice, collaboration, or even co-supervision from another professor at your school. Be careful though, because your current professor may be sensitive about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you consider changing supervisors, subject and the place where PhD is carried out, it looks to me that you in fact consider quitting your current PhD and start a new one. You need to check your offer and contract which you signed when you accepted the PhD, but it is very unlikely that you can take this funding with you.

Seeing that you're having difficulties locating the ERC website, it is clear that you were not yourself applying for the funding. I suspect that the University where you are studying applied for [ITN](http://ec.europa.eu/research/mariecurieactions/about/innovative-training-networks_en) and you have got a place in this network. This is technically not your funding, hence you most likely can not take it with you.

Comment: The biggest problem is represented by my supervisors. And I am afraid that, because of them, I don't believe in this project any more. The application for fellowship wasn't done by me. I was accepted by my supervisors for this position. So, yes, ITN is my situation.

Comment: How much freedom does ITN offer to me? Do I have to pay anything back and in which conditions?

Comment: @Newbie You don't have to pay anything back, a MSCA ITN fellowship is one of the best in the world. Actually you don't even have to do a PhD, its more of a research position. The only problem for your professors is that they will have to find someone else to finish the project, but that is their problem, not yours. You can also move into a different topic as long as they agree.